How to embed executed python code in a markdown file
I’m thinking to do a static site (using maybe sveltekit/nextjs/nuxtjs… but open to other alternatives) where some code blocks in a markdown file are first executed, like:
```python-exec
def f(x):
    return x + 1
print(f(42))
```

should be equivalent to something like:
```python
def f(x):
    return x + 1
print(f(42))
```
Output:
```
43
```

Ideally, this should be cached somewhere so that when I deploy it it does not need to execute it again.
I once built a similar library for LaTeX files here, but I’d like a similar tool for MDX files. Is there a solution for this?
